# Postgresql: Disallow duplicate value to be inserted if already in any of multiple columns?

Tags: postgresql, table, unique-constraint

Suppose I have 3 columns:

**Critical**, **Medium**, **Low**

And I have data `UUID`s to be inserted from another tables. And I want to disallow insertion of same UUID in any of the column if it is already present any one of these columns. How can I do that in postgres? How should I setup my table?

example:

```
--------------------------
|Critical | High  | Low   |
--------------------------
|   A     | null  | null  |
|   null  |  B    | null  |
---------------------------
```

Now when I try to insert B (again) in any column Critical, High or Low. It should ignore the insert.

Comment: Do you want to forbid or ignore the insert?

Comment: i want to ignore it

Comment: *Now when I try to insert B (again) in any column Critical, High or Low. It should ignore the insert.* Normalize to `(priority - value)` and set `value` as unique. Use `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`.

Comment: @Akina. How do I normalize it in postgres? could you please elaborate

Comment: Right, there is no way to do it with the table design you currently have. "Normalize" is not a database operation, it is a table design technique.

Comment: I was actually trying to solve this issue using temporary table. Instead is there a exact way how can I classify into 3 arrays so that none of the elements are repeated @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: You could create a check constraint that allows exactly one not-null value for each row

Answer (score 1):

> How do I normalize it in postgres? could you please elaborate – Pax

Structure and predefined data:

```sql
-- Create table with priorities.
CREATE TABLE priorities (priority_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
                         priority VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO priorities VALUES (1, 'Critical'), 
                              (2, 'High'), 
                              (3, 'Low');

-- Create table for data. Series column added.
CREATE TABLE data (series INT NOT NULL,
                   priority_id INT NOT NULL,
       -- reference to priorities table
                   CONSTRAINT fk_priority FOREIGN KEY (priority_id) REFERENCES priorities (priority_id),
                   value VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
       -- forbid duplicated values
                   UNIQUE (series, priority_id));
```

Insertion pattern:

```
INSERT INTO data 
    VALUES {values list}
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Retrieving the information:

```
SELECT series, 
       MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE priority_id = 1) Critical,
       MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE priority_id = 2) High,
       MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE priority_id = 3) Low
FROM data
GROUP BY series
ORDER BY series;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8b67d7cc4df31390aa4db44962289082)

PS. The scheme does not allow to insert more than one value for the same priority in the same series also (see last insert).

PPS. `priorities` table is not used in shown code (it is used for reference integrity only), but you may...

Comment: Thank you. I'll study your implementation :)